# How do I add four rotating images to an animated background?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to add four rotating images to an animated background.

I can only get one image working correctly with my code below.

How can I add in the other three images?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = function(){
    render();
}
img.src = 'nano3.png';

function drawImage(img,x,y,r,sx,sy){
    sx=sx||0;
    sy=sy||0;
    r=(r*Math.PI/180)||0;
    var cr = Math.cos(r);
    var sr = Math.sin(r);
    ctx.setTransform(cr,sr,-sr,cr,x-(cr*sx-sr*sy),y-(sr*sx+cr*sy)); 
    ctx.drawImage(img,1,2);
}

var r = 1;
function render(){
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); 
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,800,800);

    drawImage(img,50,50,r++,img.width/2,img.height/2);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you out, I just created an object known as `rotatingimage` which stores a location, an image and its current rotation. We call the 'draw' method in a 'setInterval' function call which deals with rotating the canvas and then drawing the sprite correctly.

Just a note rotating many images can cause the canvas to lag also the `CurrentRotation` variable never gets reset to 0 when it reaches `>359` so the `CurrentRotation` variable will keep going higher and higher, you may want to fix that in the `RotatingImage.prototype.Draw` function

jsFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/xd8brfrk/

Javascript

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function RotatingImage(x, y, spriteUrl, rotationSpeed) {
  this.XPos = x;
  this.YPos = y;
  this.Sprite = new Image();
  this.Sprite.src = spriteUrl;
  this.RotationSpeed = rotationSpeed;
  this.CurrentRotation = 0;
}

RotatingImage.prototype.Draw = function(ctx) {
    ctx.save();
  this.CurrentRotation += 0.1;
  ctx.translate(this.XPos + this.Sprite.width/2, this.YPos + this.Sprite.height/2);
  ctx.rotate(this.CurrentRotation); 
  ctx.translate(-this.XPos - this.Sprite.width/2, -this.YPos - this.Sprite.height/2);
  ctx.drawImage(this.Sprite, this.XPos, this.YPos);
  ctx.restore();
}

var RotatingImages = [];

RotatingImages.push(new RotatingImage(50, 75, "http://static.tumblr.com/105a5af01fc60eb94ead3c9b342ae8dc/rv2cznl/Yd9oe4j3x/tumblr_static_e9ww0ckmmuoso0g4wo4okosgk.png", 1));

RotatingImages.push(new RotatingImage(270, 25, "http://static.tumblr.com/105a5af01fc60eb94ead3c9b342ae8dc/rv2cznl/Yd9oe4j3x/tumblr_static_e9ww0ckmmuoso0g4wo4okosgk.png", 1));

RotatingImages.push(new RotatingImage(190, 180, "http://static.tumblr.com/105a5af01fc60eb94ead3c9b342ae8dc/rv2cznl/Yd9oe4j3x/tumblr_static_e9ww0ckmmuoso0g4wo4okosgk.png", 1));

RotatingImages.push(new RotatingImage(100, 270, "http://static.tumblr.com/105a5af01fc60eb94ead3c9b342ae8dc/rv2cznl/Yd9oe4j3x/tumblr_static_e9ww0ckmmuoso0g4wo4okosgk.png", 1));

setInterval(function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000"
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (var i = 0; i < RotatingImage.length; i++) {
    var rotatingImage = RotatingImages[i];
    rotatingImage.Draw(ctx);
  }
}, (1000 / 60));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use save and restore to apply different transform to your drawing

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore